# When could Futures be more appropriate than Actors (or vice versa) in Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, future

Suppose I need to run a few concurrent tasks.

I can wrap each task in a `Future` and wait for their completion. Alternatively I can create an `Actor` for each task. Each `Actor` would execute its task (e.g. upon receiving a "start" message) and send the result back.

I wonder *when* I should use the former (with `Future`s) and the latter (with `Actor`s) approach and *why* the `Future` approach is considered better for the case described above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it is syntactically simpler.

```
val tasks: Seq[() => T] = ???
val futures = tasks map {
  t => future { t() }
}
val results: Future[Seq[T]] = Future.sequence(futures)
```

The `results` future you can then wait on using `Await.result` or you can map it further/use it in for-comprehension or install callbacks on it.

Compare that to instantiating all the actors, sending messages to them, coding their `receive` blocks, receiving responses from them and shutting them down -- that would generally require more boilerplate.

Comment: The difference is also in the underlying implementation, but the Actor model is in general a more powerful and expressive programming model -- you could probably create an API similar to the Futures API using actors. Implementing actors using futures would be more cumbersome.

Comment: Ok, I see the difference between the models. Could you explain also the difference b/w the implementations ?

Comment: The futures API generally works by creating a fork/join task and pushing it to the fork/join pool which then assigns the task to one of the worker threads. It sometimes optimizes this (last time I checked) by executing the tasks scheduled for execution from within a single future in bulk. The actors implementation also relies on a thread pool and handling messages stored in an actor mailbox from within a task, but I am not knowledgeable enough in its internals to tell you more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is interesting which tasks fit the `actor` model (or `future` model) better. I will think about it.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, use the simplest concurrency model that fits your application, rather than the most powerful.  Ordering from simplest to most complex would be sequential programming->parallel collections->futures->stateless actors->stateful actors->threads with software transactional memory->threads with explicit locking->threads with lock-free algorithms.  Pick the first one in this list that solves your problem.  The farther down that list you go, the greater the complexities and risks, so you're better off trading simplicity for conceptual power.

Comment: Where from did you take that sequence? For me, it looks inconsistent, as using futures implies threads with explicit locking. And, where are threads with implicit locking (using blocking queue). Besides, what how many inputs can your actor have? if only one (scala and akka actors), then you should list multi-input actors separately. If actors you mean can have multiple inputs, then there is no difference between stateless and stateful actors (state is a token passed to an additional input).

Comment: The list was just personal opinion.  You're changes are reasonable, except that futures in no way implies threads and explicit locking. Side-effect-free futures effectively model dataflow variables, and gain concurrency without allowing non-determinism.

Comment: Futures in Java (java.util.concurrent.Future), and in most other languages (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) are blocking, and so imply threads. What futures are you talking about?

Comment: Implementation of futures does indeed imply threads under the covers, like pretty much any concurrency construct.  That said, I will assert that it is a simpler model that threads in general, simply because it is (in the absence of side effects), deterministic and capable of supporting local reasoning.  Parallel collections and stateless actors have similar characteristics.  Note that these models are actually weaker than threads-with-locks.  There are concurrent programs that you can't create with side-effect-free futures, including but not limited to those with race conditions.

Comment: I would consider futures as a particular case of blocking queues, and apply your considerations of futures to all blocking queues. Anyway, I like this discussion, but I am afraid it have become off-topic here. Let me know if you'd like to continue in another place (email addr is in my profile).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think that actors are useful when you have interacting threads. In your case, it appears to be that all the jobs are independent; I would use futures.

Comment: Reading the other answers, I think a new one should be a little bit more elaborated.